# Microsoft speech service to listen multiple audio

Tags: python, audio-streaming, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I am developing a project using python in speech recognition. In that, I need to recognize audio from multiple microphones. The application is based on Azure Cognitive Services and the assistant need to handle multiple microphones. I have seen similar [SO thread for 2 microphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71636111/listening-for-2-or-more-microphones-using-microsoft-speech-services). But in this scenario I need to handle multiple microphones, more than 2.

My question is to know, is there any way to connect multiple microphones to my device to access the application features?

I am using latest python version. I didn't find anything specific to multiple audio handling at the same moment. Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Please give us some sample code of the things you have tried

Comment: As this is my research work, I cannot upload any code block because of the restrictions. Can you please understand it technically and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of creating an array of microphone inputs and there are limitations and usage patterns for each array size.

As mentioned, in [Listening for 2 or more microphones using Microsoft speech services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71636111/listening-for-2-or-more-microphones-using-microsoft-speech-services)

We have different channels in array. Check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk-microphone)

There is an array of 2,4,7 channels.

2 Microphones - It's a linear channel.
4,7 Microphones - It's a circular channel.

More than 7 it is not possible to connect. Try to achieve your work within 7 microphones. As you are unable to share the code block due to some restrictions mentioned in the comment. Orally I have tried to share the solution.